# Creating and returning file via C function

Tags: c, file, file-io

What I'm trying to do is to write a function that creates a file, fills it with data and returns the file to main(). The question is - what is the right way to "return file". Should I pass pointer / file descriptor or just disregard all this and use filename?

EDIT: doing the right way (I hope):

```
int mkrandfile(const char *name, int range, int qnt) 
{
    FILE *afile;
    int i = 0;

    if (afile = fopen(name, "w+"))
    {
        while((i <= qnt) && fprintf(afile, "%d ", rand() % range - range/2))
            i++;
        fclose(afile);
        if (i != qnt + 1)
            return -2;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why does anything have to be returned? The caller of the function knows the filename and the `FILE*` is useless since you call `fclose()` on it at the end of the function.

Comment: While you're editing that code and changing the return type to `int` (gotta at least *tell* the caller whether it *worked* or not) you may want to (a) check the return value of that `fopen()` call for success, (b) check the return value of each `fprintf()` and (c) return a meaningful value to the caller indicating whether anything went wrong or all is well. Finally seed the RNG *once* at the start of the program. It shouldn't be in this function at all. (And yes, your comment is accurate. It is bad).

Comment: There's no unique answer, it depends on the needs of the caller; after all, we have `tmpfile`, `tmpnam`, `mktemp`, `mkstemp` and god-knows how many other variants for basically the same task (creating a temporary file).

Comment: @WhozCraig, always check for errors, I get it :) And thanks for the RNG hint.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I'm creating a persistent file here. Thank you, I'm aware of these functions and have used some a few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that returning `afile` from that function is wrong.  Once the file is closed, that file handle is no longer valid. Use of it by the caller would result in undefined behavior.

While it is probably not the best idea from a modularity standpoint, you could leave the file open and then return the handle.  But I think one of the following might be better:

- Pass in an opened file handle to the function (let the caller open and close it).
- Make the caller open the file again on its own.

The first option may be more efficient when file caching by the OS (if applicable here) is considered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll go with the second option. I have to reopen the file for reading either way.